# Application crash when try to make video call using QBVideoChat

Tags: ios, quickblox

I am developing an application for video call, but when try to make call application crash with following error

```
2014-12-30 00:00:50.866 closeChat[28683:3791106] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString xmlChar]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x19b4a8'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x29e5949f 0x3764fc8b 0x29e5e8b9 0x29e5c7d7 0x29d8e058 0xf2bc5 0xee3a9 0x89923 0x89d89 0x29e1627b 0x88c05 0x889af 0x371b3 0x2d34c9fb 0x2d34c9a1 0x2d337613 0x2d34c40d 0x2d3111ad 0x29e1fd95 0x29e1d453 0x29e1d85b 0x29d6b3c1 0x29d6b1d3 0x311690a9 0x2d37afa1 0x67189 0x37bcfaaf)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I used the following code:

```
self.videoChat = [[QBChat instance] createAndRegisterVideoChatInstance];
self.videoChat.viewToRenderOpponentVideoStream = self.imgOppenentViewView;
self.videoChat.viewToRenderOwnVideoStream = self.imgOwnVideoView;

self.videoChat.useHeadphone = 1;
self.videoChat.useBackCamera = 1;
NSMutableDictionary *videoChatConfiguration = [[QBSettings videoChatConfiguration] mutableCopy];
//
[videoChatConfiguration setObject:AVCaptureSessionPresetLow forKey:kQBVideoChatFrameQualityPreset];
[videoChatConfiguration setObject:@10 forKey:kQBVideoChatVideoFramesPerSecond];
//
[QBSettings setVideoChatConfiguration:videoChatConfiguration];
[QBChat instance].delegate = self;
[self.videoChat callUser:[self.opponentID intValue] conferenceType:QBVideoChatConferenceTypeAudioAndVideo];
```

Comment: What does the stack look like when you crash?  (Type 'bt' at the (lldb) prompt.)

Answer (score 0):

I've tested video sample Quickblox with your settings and video call works as expected.

Please try to setup Quickblox with CocoaPods and see if error happens again

http://quickblox.com/developers/IOS-how-to-connect-Quickblox-framework#CocoaPods

And there is a new WebRTC sample you can test. It has more features and preferred to use.